# Twitter bootstrap 2 - custom button styling not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using TB 2 and I am trying to create a new button style in CSS. This is the selector pattern I am using in my CSS:

```
.btn.btn-create { background-color: #D14836; color: #FFFFFF; }
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
     <div id="page-right-column" class="span4">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <a href="#display-popup" class="btn btn-create pull-right" data-toggle="modal">Create New</a>
```

When the page is displayed, the button color is gray, and the color specified in the CSS is only displayed as I move the mouse over the button - what am I doing wrong?

How do I correctly style a TB button color with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
.btn.btn-create { 
    background-color: #D14836;
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    background-image: none; /* the background-image needs to be reset */
}
```

Comment: Simple when you know how ! :)