# Change the css color properties of a button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I change the css color properties of a button in the bootstrap framework? 
For example, one of my buttons...

```
<button type="button" id="button1" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" onclick="checkAnswer(0)">Some text</button>
```

Some jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Wrong answer! The selected button turns red.
  $("#button1").click(function(){
      $("btn-primary").css("background-color", "red");
  });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: see this for full expl. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415030/twitter-bootstrap-2-custom-button-styling-not-working/13415671#13415671 (there is some issues to take care off)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the commment not gave any sense :), here in code

```
<button type="button" id="button1" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" onclick="checkAnswer(0)">Some text</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#button1").click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-image','none')
    .css('background-color','#FF0000') //red
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for not replying to the comment. I had to step out, just after posting. The example works great. 
Interesting how the bg image needs to be reset. I'll look into why so.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the stylesheet, you could use different bootstrap options by changing the class, for red:

```
class="btn btn-danger btn-large"
```

or for blue:

```
class="btn btn-primary btn-large"
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-options